# Could we recover Mongo records from the data files only without namespace files?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4, mongo-repair

I am missing a namespace file from the Mongo db path. I only have data files with number extensions (e.g. report.4,report.5). Is there any way to recover the mongodb dump from the data files?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. You have MMAPv1 engine in use... If your mongodb version is BEFORE 3.0, you can use mongodump and --dbpath parameter to read data directly from data files.